# Passport.js - Serializer of user object fails during authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, serialization, passport.js

I got a problem with the Passport.js module and Express.js. This is my code and I want to use the google provider login for trying. I always get the message: Error: Failed to serialize user into session.
When i tried to see what was in the serializer, I got the message "User object received by serializer" shows that the object passed to the serializer (passport.serializeUser) is an instance of Mongoose's Query, rather than a complete user object.

```
Error: Failed to serialize user into session
   at pass (C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:278:19)
   at serialized (C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:283:7)
   at C:\Users\vueForm\app.js:42:5
   at pass (C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:291:9)
   at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:296:5)
   at C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\passport\lib\sessionmanager.js:33:10
   at C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\express-session\session\store.js:54:5
   at C:\Users\vueForm\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:377:13
   at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

[image]

```
app.use(
session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  cookie: { httpOnly: false, secure: true, maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000},
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: MongoStore.create({mongoUrl: process.env.DB_URI}),
 }))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

connectToDatabase()

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
 console.log("User objet get by serializer :", user);
 done(null, user._id);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne(id, function (err, user) {
  done(err, user);
  });
});


passport.use(
new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.Google_clientID,
  clientSecret: process.env.Google_clientSecret,
  callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
},
async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    console.log("Info send to Google :", profile);
    const existingUser = User.findOne({
      providerId: profile.id,
    })
    if (existingUser) {
        return done(null, existingUser);
    } else {
    const user = await new User({
      googleId: profile.id,
      displayName: profile.displayName,
      email: profile.email,
      photo: profile.photos[0].value,
      
    }).save();
    return done(null, user);
    }
})
)

app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));

app.get('/auth/google/callback', (req,res,next)=>{
passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/auth/google/error' }, async (error, user , info) => {
  if (error){
    return res.send({ message:error.message });
  }
  if (user){
    try {
      return res.send({
        data: result.data,
        message:'Login Successful' 
      });
    } catch (error) {
      return res.send({ message: error.message });
    }
  }
})(req,res,next);

res.redirect(`http://localhost:8080/home}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the deserializeUser function. The User.findOne function expects a query object but you are passing the _id directly as an argument. Also, I think handling error explicitely might be good for readability.

```js
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOne({ _id: id }, function (err, user) {
  error ? done(err, null) :  done(null, user)
})
```

Out of curiousity, Do you really need the entire user object to be available in every single api endpoint? Can you not avoid the need to query the database during each request? I mean can you not just do something like this,

```js
passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=> done(null, id))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply, i try this but it dosent working, i still have the same problem, to answer your question, I need the user object for later to get the user data for a form...

Comment: It should work. do you have all the code in a single file? like you printed in your question?

Comment: All of my code is here >> https://codeshare.io/j0ZkWK